# Any way to eliminate time lag with sshfs?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, sshfs

If I rsync a directory with some remote directory under an sshfs
management, even if the rsync process finishes synching the
directory contents, there seems to be a time lag for the sshfs
directory to get updated. It is unintuitive and makes some
automation process relying on sshfs contents unstable.

How do I eliminate the lag?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`-o cache=no` in your sshfs options will turn off caching.

---

Note: `no` should be lower case: `-o cache=NO` should give you an error!

Comment: Odd. The man page for my copy of sshfs (2.2/FUSE 2.8.1/fusermount 2.8.1/FUSE kernel interface 7.12) says `-o cache=YESNO`. Anyway, fixed.

Comment: The man page of sshfs is misleading in that it capitalizes all the option values when cap'ed values are invalid. Mine's: `-o cache=YESNO  enable caching {yes,no} (default: yes)`

Comment: Wow, nutty. Not as nutty as the docs I'm reading now, but still nutty.

Comment: Works for me `-ocache=no` as per the [SSHFS wiki](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS)